# Grouping search results when storing different values in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I have to build a report from some data stored on a MySQL table and everything was going smoothly until I noticed that we are storing multiple values in one column. This is what I mean:

```
FIELDS: ID | CHOICES | AGE
VALUES: 1 | apple|orange|pear | 23
VALUES: 2 | peach|orange|pineapple|pear | 29
```

I need to search that table and find out how many users like pear, how many like orange, etc.
It would be a GROUP BY on that value but how do I break the contents of the CHOICE column into individual fields so I can search and group them like that? This code is executed from a PHP file, so I could also pre-process the data if needed, although I would prefer to do everything in the query if possible.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is bad design. You shouldn't insert serialized values into RDBMS, that defeats the purpose of using them in the first place. Can you change the application or are you stuck with this?

Comment: I know. I'm stuck with this just for this one report but I am changing it going forward. So there is no decent way of doing this in the query? I can follow Galen's suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the database design I would recommend doing this in PHP.

Loop over the result:

```
foreach $result
    foreach $fruits
        $fruit_array[$fruit] = $id
```

Then you have an array indexed by fruit with an array of ids as a value

BUT change the database design if possible

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I'm a better HBase table designer.

Following NullUserException's comment, you'd definitely benefit from a better table schema. Something like:

Choices
USER_ID | CHOICE

Users
USER_ID | AGE

From here you could do a join to associate a user with his/her age and choice, or do a count to see how many people of age X chose fruit Y.

However, to solve your problem at hand you would have to select * and then manually count each user's preference. Using a radix-like approach wouldn't make this too bad. (Edit: See Galen's answer for the PHP code.)